# radians sometimes flipped/reversed

Tags: javascript, radians

I have a function which should be finding the middle of two radians

```
function mrad(rb,ra){return (rb+ra)/2;}
```

But sometimes when I plot the x and y with Math.sin and Math.cos the two a specified length the new coordinates are coming out at the polar opposites of what I intend.

for example; If I expect the new points to be down and to the right sometimes they are coming out as up and to the left. **The coordinates are correct apart from this!**

Here is how I plot the new x and y

```
xnew=xold-(100)*Math.cos(radian);
xnew=yold+(100)*Math.sin(radian);
```

I am guessing that it might matter if radian B (rb) is bigger than ra. I think what is happening is that I am going full circle in this case, whereas I sometimes should be instead doing something like

```
 function mrad(rb,ra){return (rb-ra)/2;}
```

My questions are

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. What would be the condition, how to tell when to do **rb-ra** vs **rb+ra**, or to put it better, how do you tell if one radian is pointing above or bellow the other?

It should look something like this

```
function mrad(rb,ra){return ((/*condition*/)?(rb-ra):(rb-ra))/2;}
```

**Edit**

To find the range I have tried to express different values to find a range in radians but cannot find anything more than a diagonal line

http://jsfiddle.net/roLLqfs6/

Also the defined length is not always 100 as it is written in the example

Comment: is this a programming question?

Comment: err yeah, there is code above ^

Comment: sounds like a math question...

Comment: I see lots of radian questions in the side bar > plus I am asking about the condition applied to a javascript statement in a function. Math and rogramming are both parts of the question, like if i posted it on a math site they would say is this really math or programming?

Answer (score 0):

It's really a maths question. You need to make sure that your angles are in the same range (either `-pi ... pi` or `0 ... 2.0 * pi`), but even then, taking the mean of them will not necessarily find the angle you are looking for - you might expect that (in degrees, for simplicity) the answer you want for 10º & 20º would be 15º, but what would you expect for 175º and -175º? I suspect you would want 180º (as this is the minor arc between them), but you will get 0º.

So, you need to test the difference, to see that they are less than 180º (pi radians) apart, and modify the answer accordingly if they are not.